# Display youtube video that contains content protected by copyright

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, youtube

I am making a scroll view in which there are multiple instances of UIWebView, each with a youtube video that user can tap and watch. I tried multiple approaches how to this (I mean, what to put in UIWebView), the one that worked best was from https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

However, I have a video that doesn't play, instead it displays "This video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites" (it worked fine at first and I wasn't getting this message, no idea why it stopped working). Is there a way to make such video play in iOS app? If yes, how?

P.S.
I don't want to kick the user out of my app and send him to youtube app or safari.
I also want to be able to count how many times did user play the video, but this topic is probably big enough for a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading video with this:

```
    [_videoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/"]];
```